# Read pom information from child pom via Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, pom.xml

I hope someone can help me with a little problem I have while reading from a pom file with jenkins. Thanks in advance.
I know that one can use the `readMavenPom`function like this:

```
pom = readMavenPom file:'pom.xml'
```

but this only helps me with getting information from the parent pom in my maven project. I would like to read from the child pom like this:

```
pom = readMavenPom file:'path/to/my/pom/pom.xml'
```

But when executed, i always receive null as an answer. I tried some things such as using a relative path from my jenkins workspace and changing around the path itself, but nothing helped me this far.

Comment: Is the POM path correct?

Comment: yes, as far as i know it should be correct.

Comment: `path/to/my/pom/pom.xml` is called "realtive" ..whereas `/path/to/my/pom/pom.xml` is called "absolute"! (tiny character, but *big* difference!;) And: Hi & welcome to [so]!

Comment: `pom.xml` is relative (to the "execution" or some other path), `/pom.xml` absolute (in the underlying file system;)

Comment: To be sure, please introduce the istruction `sh "ls -l "` in order to see if you are on the right path.